# what is the use of the property spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.partitioned

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

What will happen If partitionCount (spring.cloud.stream.bindings..producer.partitionCount) is greater than 1 and consumer.partitioned (spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.partitioned) is false  (Using Kafka)

Comment: I would guess tha a rebalance will happen since `autoRebalanceEnabled=true` by default https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_consumer_properties

Comment: @Felipe , then what is the use of this property(spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.partitioned), i mean when i need to make it true or false

Comment: @Felipe , With Kafka, if `autoRebalanceEnabled` is `true` (default), Kafka takes care of distributing partitions across instances, and these properties are not required, is this correct?

Comment: You mean that Kafka takes care fo distributing data across partitions. Have you test it in your code? Test it and open the Kafka dashboard then we can see the configuration of the topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Kafa binder, the property `spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.partitioned` is not relevant. You can skip setting this property on the consumer side. This property's default value is `false`. Since Kafka has built-in partitioning support, the binder will simply delegate to Kafka broker and Kafka decides on which partitions to consume from. If you only have one consumer, then it will consume from all the partitions. If you have more than one consumer, Kafka will do a rebalance and split the partitions across the available consumers (assuming that the `autoRebalanceEnabled` property remains `true` to it's default value).

You can set `spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.partitioned` to true, if you want to set instance index id on the consumers (for e.g if you want to run the app on certain platforms or achieve static partitioning). In this case, you need to provde the instance index or list of instance index to the consumer. However, I think this is irrelvant for your use case.

The upshot here is that you can safely ignore, `spring.cloud.stream.bindings..consumer.partitioned` on the consumer side if you are using Kafka binder and auto rebalance is enabled.

We have some basic partitioning samples [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/partitioning-samples) that you may want to take a look at.